# How to connect to docker image on mac os

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am installing docker on mac os. I know that there is a docker-machine installed and running between my mac os and the docker images. When I start one docker image, I can't ping the image from my mac os, instead I have to connect to these images from the docker-machine. I wonder whether there is a way to allow me to connect to the docker images from the mac os.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically done by exposing ports to the docker-machine. For example, you might map the SSH port like this:

```
docker run -d -p 2022:22 my-image
```

This will bind port 2022 on the docker-machine to port 22 inside the container. Now you can gain access by using the docker-machine's IP, like this (assuming `default` docker-machine):

```
ssh -p 2022 user@$(docker-machine ip default)
```

Of course, this requires your container to expose a service on port 22. You'll have to refer to your container's documentation to see what services are being exposed.

If desired, you can also configure access to the services via `localhost`, rather than using the docker-machine IP. Doing so would require some networking config in your docker-machine driver. Assuming you are using VirtualBox (the default driver for Mac OS X installs), you can configure port forwarding in the VirtualBox UI or via `VBoxManage` (documentation link below).

Docker documentation for exposing ports: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports

VirtualBox documentation for port forwarding:
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward

Comment: This way works for one docker image. If I have multiple docker images running, I have to assign different port for different docker image. Is there another way to let me have access on the docker images by IP address?

Comment: You are correct @ZhaoYi, you would have to map a port for each container. I don't know of any other way.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that I understand it:

A docker-machine is like a virtual machine.  A container is based off of the virtual machine (docker-machine), but is completely isolated from other containers (it has it's own file system, process trees, etc).  An image is just a set of layers of containers that have been saved together.  So the word "image" and the word "container" could get inter-mingled in a few contexts.  Container usually refers to the top-most layer of an image (and is the "write" layer).

The reason I address this is because from your question, I'm not entirely sure what terminology you are trying to use.

You can SSH into both the docker-machine image as well as the containers.

To SSH into a running container, you can use

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME bash
```

To SSH into a running docker-machine image, you can use

```
docker-machine ssh DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME
```

I can think of only a few reasons why you would want to SSH into a docker-machine, but it is possible with the command above.  Almost always, you will be working with docker containers.  That's the whole reason for Docker in the first place - a container management system.

Comment: I am using ansible-playbook to setup environment configuration on the docker containers. Ansible is using SSH so I need to run ansible from my mac os in order to configure my docker containers. Since my containers can't be accessed from mac os by ssh, I can't run ansible. So is there a way for me to access these containers by its ip address?

Comment: @ZhaoYi You could possibly use VirtualBox to cut straight in.  You could load up your machine with the configuration to not be headless.  I'm not entirely sure if this can be done, but it's a thought.

Comment: @ZhaoYi You can access the container via default IP 192.168.99.100, not? See https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/: `docker-machine ip default`

Comment: I am able to access the IP 192.168.99.100. But I can't access to each of the container IP.